# Rancher 2 Kubernetes certificates expired with error x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes

I'm using Rancher version 2.2.8 and when access to Rancher, I got the error **x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid**, I found that when the Rancher docker image deployed time exceed 12 months, it will get this error. My process of deploying Rancher is build a docker image which extends from **rancher/rancher:v2.2.8** and combine my ssl certificate at **/etc/rancher/ssl/**, I have many Rancher like this for all services and they all got this error after 1 year. I found [this article](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/909/rancher2-kubernetes-cluster-certificates-expired-how-to-rotate) have the same error to me but I can't find the folder `/etc/kubernetes` in the docker container (tried to `ls -a` but this folder doesn't show on the list). I tried to rotate certificate for all cluster on Rancher by clicking `Rotate Certificates` on Rancher UI before it exceeds 1 year but it doesn't help. Currently I fixed this issue by upgrading Rancher version follow this [doc](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/other-installation-methods/single-node-docker/single-node-upgrades/) but I want to find another elegant way to deal with this issue.

Comment: did you check `ll  /etc/rancher/ssl/` ?

Comment: In the folder `/etc/rancher/ssl/`, I have cert.pem and key.pem, all are latest and valid ssl cert

Comment: Did you followed official [Rancher documentation](https://rancher.com/blog/2019/kubernetes-certificate-expiry-and-rotation-in-rancher-kubernetes-clusters) ? After 1 year you have to rotate certificates and after that they will be valid for 10 years. You mentioned, you didnt find them in `/etc/kubernetes` but did you chacked hidden folder  `.tmp` - `/etc/kubernetes/.tmp` ? Please follow steps from docs and tell which step you are unable to execute.

Comment: I rotate certificate by UI and it show success message alert but the folder `/kubernetes` doesn't exist in `/etc` of my rancher docker container so I cannot verify if it success or not. My container only has a folder `/etc/ssl/certs` but I can't find any `.pem` files in the rancher document in here